# How to make an Intent in Alertdialog clicking ListView item?

Tags: android

Hi,

I'm trying to do these steps:
1)Select item(song_title) on ListView
2)Once item selected Alertdialog has started(with list of "Listen" and "Download")
**3)Selected one of two items on Alertdialog

4)Create Intent with extra to start Activity(download file)**

Don't understand how to implement steps 3 and 4.

Here is part of code with ItemClickListener:

```
ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(null, ". Position: " + position );
        showDialog(position);
    }
    });
```

And part with creating dialog

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
final String[] service = {"Play music", "Download"};
adb.setTitle("Choose service");
    switch(id){
    case 0:
            Log.d(null, service[id] + ". Position: " );
            adb.setItems(service, myClickListener);
            break;
    case 1:
            Log.d(null, service[id] + ". Position: " );
            adb.setItems(service, myClickListener);

    break;
}

return adb.create();
}
```

It works well with 2 items(songs), but I want to alter code for case when there are more than 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

Answering on my question )

Here is code that work well for me:

```
ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final int selectedPosition = position;
                final String[] service = {"Play music", "Download"};
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Choose service");
                adb.setItems(service, new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch(which){
                        case 0:
                            Intent playIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayMusicActivity.class);
                            playIntent.putExtra("songIndex", selectedPosition);
                            Log.d(null, which + ". Position: " + selectedPosition );
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadActivity.class);
                            downloadIntent.putExtra("songIndex", selectedPosition);
                            Log.d(null, which + ". Position: " + selectedPosition );
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            }
            });
```